# System.Array vs Byte[] When using CodeDom

Tags: c#, arrays, codedom

I am referencing a COM dll file using CodeDom. The function within the dll file has parameters as follows:

```
Public Function Foo(fooString As String, fooByte() As Byte) 
End Function
```

When this dll file is referenced directly by Visual Studio (Not using CodeDom), I call this function as follows - and the solution builds with no problems:

```
Byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes("Test.exe");
DllName.DllClass dll_obj_reference = new DllName.DllClass();

dll_obj_reference.Foo("data", b);
```

**NOTE:**
Although I am sending a byte array to the function (as requested by VB6), Visual Studio is actually asking for type `System.Array`. For whatever reason, the solution still builds fine, and I am able to call the function `Foo` with no problems at all.

However, I am not so lucky when doing this all through CodeDom. I add the interop.DllName as a reference to the generated project, and I call just the same way. This time, though, CodeDom spits back an error saying that it cannot convert type byte[] to type ref System.Array.

So, my question - finally:
How can I convert the byte array shown above to type System.Array? I cannot find any articles online.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: @BenVoigt Updated with the correct formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it wants an array passed by reference, you'd do:

```
dll_obj_reference.Foo("data", ref b);
```

Comment: No, I'm getting an error saying the following:

'Argumenet 2: Cannot convert from 'ref byte[]' to 'reef System.Array'

Comment: That should say "ref System.Array" of course. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Evan: Then try `Array a = b; dll_obj_reference.Foo("data", ref a); if (a != b) { /* figure out how to copy the elements from the new array created inside the DLL, given to you as a */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast byte array to System.Array

```
Byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes("Test.exe");

Array barr = (Array)b;

DllName.DllClass dll_obj_reference = new DllName.DllClass();

dll_obj_reference.Foo("data", barr);
```